# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in compiled-templates.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I was working on first application in ember where the versions of handle bars and ember.js were quite old.

I am using bower to install all dependencies. But once I got error in console while running the application, I specified the version of ember.js to 1.8 and that of handlebar to 2.0.0 in bower.json file. But now as the templates were little old I started getting error like **'Unknown template object: function while using handlebars 2.0'**. To resolve this error I used steps mentioned [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html) .

But still I get a new error saying **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**.
Can anyone please suggest how to upgrade the templates now? Or there is some other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars 2.0 wasn't supported until Ember 1.9.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kingpin2k but now when I have specified **1.11.0-beta.1+canary.4a1010a4** version of ember.js and handles bar version as 2.0.0. I get the same error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**.

Comment: Where, who's throwing the error, please provide either the code/template, or an example using emberjs.jsbin.com

Answer (score 0):

I had to update a few dependencies mentioned in package.json. - ember-template-compiler of node.
The solution mentioned on [this link](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/5392142-uncaught-error-unknown-template-object-function-when-using-easyform-with-ember-cli-htmlbars-and-handlebars-2-0) was useful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In production version `handlebars.runtime.js` is being used instead of `handlebars.js`. The runtime version doesn't have `Handlebars.compile` method. If you are using ember-cli then you can replace `new EmberApp();` with

```
new EmberApp({
   vendorFiles: {
     'handlebars.js': {
       production: 'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js'
     }
   }
 });
```

for reference:
 http://www.ember-cli.com/#customizing-a-built-in-asset